# VS2008 XAML Designer exception "Key cannot be null" when using default styles from a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml

I'm using a shared ResourceDictionary to define default styles and having major conflicts with the XAML Designer in Visual Studio 2008. *Key cannot be null* appears for all attempts to show the XAML design view.

The dictionary is merged into App.xaml (to be used by all windows) and has a number of styles setting the defaults for controls, so they are defined as shown below **without a key**. If you add an x:Key attribute to the styles, they are no longer applied by default. I don't want to have to put explicit Style clauses on every control but it looks like I might have to.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="windowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The full exception error message with stack:

```
Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.get_Item(Object key)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.AssemblyNode.For(Assembly assembly, Boolean includeInternal)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.ReflectionProjectNode.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName name, Boolean includeInternal)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildAssemblies()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.XmlElement.FindElementType(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
   at MS.Internal.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootType()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Documents.Trees.MarkupDocumentTreeManager.get_RootType()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Documents.MarkupDocumentManager.CalculateLoadErrorState()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Documents.MarkupDocumentManager.get_LoadState()
   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Comment: Does any default style cause this, or aren't you sure? Can you try the default styles one-by-one to see for which control or controls you're running into the problem?

Comment: I tried for ComboBox, TextBox and Button individually and with several - same result. It builds and runs fine, just the editor barfing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would require a key, but you can try the following

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks, I was trying to remember the format of the "default key" to try the same thing myself.

Comment: AARRRGGGHHH! It's back and the apparent success of that key clause was not the answer, although it does seem to make it a bit more stable. Rebuilding seems to fix about 80% of the time.

Comment: Ahh it's one of those random errors, all I can suggest is maybe creating a new project and slowly transferring your code over to see if you can find what's causing the error

Comment: I have this problem and it is because I am referencing a mixed mode C++/CLI and native C++ dll. I haven't pin pointed the problem yet though.