# Different selection colors for different DataGrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multidatatrigger

I'm trying to set different colors to different rows in datagrid, based on Type of the row and whether it is selected:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ActiveCellStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                 <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                 <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>      
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDFE6ED"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                 <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                 <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>      
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6CAFF1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        ...
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When I run this, I'm getting ArgumentException: key cannot be null.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Might be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189131/vs2008-xaml-designer-exception-key-cannot-be-null-when-using-default-styles-fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `MultiTrigger` you use `Property` and with `MultiDataTrigger` you use `Binding`, you can't combine them. So change

```
<Condition Property="IsSelected"
```

to

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=IsSelected}"
```

and it should work

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ActiveCellStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                 Path=IsSelected}"
                                       Value="False"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDFE6ED"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="0"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                             Path=IsSelected}"
                           Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6CAFF1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```